# Вызов функции из соседнего файла PHP

Tags: php

Парни я уже находил подобные темы как на этом форуме так и на других. Но я так и не понял лично в моем случае в чем проблема?

Вопрос следующий: Какого черта PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function a() in /var/www/testing/test.php:5

Код test.php

```
<?php 

    require "test1.php";
    
    a();
?>
```

Код test1.php

```
<?

    function a(){
        echo "a";
    }
?>
```

Данные файлы были созданы как пример. И сразу говорю я пробовал и require и include и их аналоги _once. Так же все файлы находятся в каталоге /var/www/testing/.

Надеюсь хоть кто-то сможет мне объяснить что не так. И огромная просьба, давайте без всяких этих проверь а вдруг не в одном и том же каталоге и т.п. Я не такой уж и новичок.

Comment: Опция `short_open_tag` включена? Я спрашиваю потому что в файле `test1.php` у Вас использован short open tag.

Comment: @Simon сенкс, я даже и не знал что это включается. А как и где не подскажешь? Топерь вроде работает =) Пойду на осн. файлах проверю

Comment: опцию-то надо выключить, а писать везде нормальный пхп тег